# Trying to loops through multiple cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I've searched online and found a few solutions, but none of them make sense to me. I'm wondering why this specifically doesn't work:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A5:A10")
    For Each cell In rng
        Dim contents As String: contents = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ROI's").Range("cell").Value
        MsgBox (contents)
    Next cell
```

(BTW this is within a larger macro which works)

It keep saying that the error is on the third line

Comment: Change `"cell"` to `cell.address(0,0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Could you also just do `...contents = cell.Value`?

Comment: Though it would be better to define the sheets when setting rng, `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ROI's").Range("A5:A10")` then `contents = cell.Value`

Comment: @BruceWayne see my second comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Any "best practice" thoughts on Declaring and assigning a variable on the same line?  I'm going to guess to recommend against doing so, since it makes the code a little harder to read?

Comment: @BruceWayne personal preference, I personally do not, but that is me.

Comment: @ScottCraner You mean like this, right?/ Dim contents As String: contents = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ROI's").Range("cell.address(0,0)").Value/ Still doesn't work :(

Comment: No, without the quotes, it is a variable not a string.

Comment: `contents = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ROI's").Range(cell.address(0,0)).Value`

Comment: Ok thanks @ScottCraner I went with your suggestion in your 2nd comment. Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Scott Craners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) answer, take the parenthesis away from around `contents` in `MsgBox (contents)`, you are not placing it into a variable so it should not be enclosed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub try2()


Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim contents As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

For Each cell In rng
    contents = ws.Range(cell.Address(0, 0)).Value
    MsgBox (contents)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I've been practicing wtih various problems concerning VBA...the above is just a snippet synthesizing what all the fine people above me have said about making this work. My 2 cents, brackets or not around the contents variable, the result is the same.